# SSRS Report Builder 3.0 Line Chart: How to chart Duration per day?

Tags: reporting-services, line, charts

Working with SSRS Report Builder 3.0. I want a Line Chart where the dates are on the X axis and the Durations are on the Y-axis. It's so easy to get this on Excel, but SSRS is not that intuitive when it comes to charting. The table below is actually larger. But the I want the dates on X to tilt 90 degrees and the Y-axis to show intervals in the format of the Duration values. I've tried the obvious but what comes up is either blank chart or a jumble in the beginning of the chart. Your help is appreciated! Thanks!

`|StartDate|Package |Task  |Duration

|1/1/2011  |Pkg1    |Task1 |00:04:36

|1/10/2011 |Pkg1    |Task1 |00:12:06

|1/11/2011 |Pkg1    |Task1 |00:15:55

|1/12/2011 |Pkg1    |Task1 |00:16:39

|1/13/2011 |Pkg1    |Task1 |00:14:17

|1/14/2011 |Pkg1    |Task1 |00:15:30 `

Answer (score 0):

After converting the Durations to a decimal, the chart started working. Can't see how this is not possible using standard time spans though. Oh well.